# PID controller for 2 DOF system

Tags: control-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I have system : [2 dof system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeJnW.png)

Speed of the second mass wanted to be controlled by a PID. The transfer function of the system is :

s/( s^4 - 1.89e-17 s^3 + 2 s^2 - 1.408e-16 s - 3.263e-32)

I could not find a viable PID controller for the system. Even the sisotool could not optimized one. Is there a viable PID controller for this plant? If not how can I know this "instabilizability" from the transfer function?

Comment: Are you sure that your transfer function is correct, because those really small numbers seem to be due to rounding errors.

Comment: Also at really low frequencies that spring "feels" really stiff and the two masses act as one mass, in which case the system should act as a double integrator. But after removing the really small numbers then your transfer function has a slope of minus one at really low frequencies.

Comment: Constants in equation of motion are taken as unity in the problem. Thus there are small numbers in the denominator.

Comment: What do you mean by "Thus there are small numbers in the denominator." if you work out the transfer function by hand then those small numbers shouldn't be there. Also there is some other mistake in your transfer function which is probably not due to rounding errors. So I would recommend you to take another close look at deriving the transfer function.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Function I showed above is the transfer function of the plant obtained from Matlab(coefficients are simplified to obtain a classical polynomial form at the denominator). The tf's(plant's) state space form is:
A1=[ 0 0 1 0 ;
        0 0 0 1 ;
       -1 1 0 0 ;
        1-1 0 0 ];

B1=[0 0 1 0]';

C1=[0 0 0 1];

Comment: I misread that you wanted to control the **speed** of the second mass, in which case your state space model is correct. To reduce numerical errors you could use: syms s, C/(eye(4)*s-A)*B

Comment: Thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly calculate the transfer function and reduce it as much as possible you should get

$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{s^3 + 2\,s}.
$$

A PID controller can be written as

$$
C(s) = \frac{D\,s^2 + P\,s + I}{s},
$$

so the open loop, while using this controller, can be written as

$$
L(s) = C(s)\,G(s) = \frac{D\,s^2 + P\,s + I}{s^4 + 2\,s^2}.
$$

The closed loop transfer function, given the open loop $L(s)$, can be calculated with $L(s)/(1+L(s))$. Applying this to the open loop which uses a PID controller gives

$$
H(s) = \frac{D\,s^2 + P\,s + I}{s^4 + (2 + D)\,s^2 + P\,s + I}.
$$

The closed loop $H(s)$ would be stable if the poles all have negative real part. A fourth order polynomial can also be written as $\prod_{n=1}^4 (s - p_n)$ with $p_n$ the $n$th root of the polynomial. Expanding this expression gives that the coefficient in front of $s^3$ term can also be expressed as $\sum_{n=1}^4 p_n$, but the given denominator has that this coefficient is equal to zero. However, if all poles need to have negative real part then that conflicts with $\sum_{n=1}^4 p_n = 0$. So it is impossible to stabilize this system with just a PID controller.

As a rule of thumb you want a minus one slope as assymptote when the open loop crosses the 0 dB line and (to make things easier for yourself) avoid that the open loop crosses the 0 dB line again. Avoiding crossing the 0 dB again would mean that it would be preferred that the 0 dB crossing lies after the resonance peak of the system. However, the slope after the resonance peak has an assymptote of minus three, so in order to get a minus one slope the controller would locally have to have a slope of plus two. A PID controller can at most add a slope increase of one, so from this it can also be concluded that a PID controller would be insufficient to control this system.

Comment: A satisfying and clear answer, thank you!